# Enviado dados via GET e POST com Java Script

Tags: php, javascript, post, get

Pessoal veja se alguém pode ajudar
Tenho uma variável chamada "ssId" onde tem uma informação que para enviar para um arquivo php, alguém pode me ajudar como fazer?

```js
function chamarSS(ssId ){
    if(ssId){
       console.log("SS: " + ssId);
    }
}
```

```html
<th style='text-align:center'><a href="javascript:;" id="ssId"  onclick="chamarSS('<?php echo $obj->SS; ?>');">DADOS</a></th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara não é nada recomendado você usar JavaScript para transporte de dados, é muito explicito e é algo muito perigoso, se você estiver trabalhando com dados importantes que podem colocar em risco perca financeira ou até extravio de alguma coisa, recomento utilizar PHP muito mais seguro.

Mas assim para você fazer uma GET 
Você pode usar tanto o getJSON(Jquery) AJAX(Jquery)

```
function recViaCep(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://viacep.com.br/ws/"+ $("#cep").val()+"/json/", 
    type: "GET",   
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      dados = response;
      $('#logradouro').val(dados.logradouro.toUpperCase());
      $('#bairro').val(dados.bairro.toUpperCase());
      $('#cidade').val(dados.localidade.toUpperCase());
      $('#estado').val(dados.uf.toUpperCase());
      initMap();    
      $("#nomeRegristro").val($("#CNPJCPF").val() + " - " + $("#nomeAnalista").val())
    }
});
```

}

Nesse exemplo estou fazendo a requisição de um JSON por AJAX, que para devidos fins não vão colocar em risco minha empresa, portanto vê o que você precisa fazer!!

`$.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
      $("div").append(field + " ");
    });
  });`

Já aqui é um exemplo de requisição por JSON

Como eu disse, tenha cuidado com o método post, o JS não vai deixar seus dados seguros